# How to fix Unable to create core [blog] Caused by: solr.SortableIntField

Tags: solr

I am trying to add search engine using `solr` and haystack and when I try to add a new core I get this error:

> ERROR: Error CREATEing SolrCore 'blog': Unable to create core [blog]
>   Caused by: solr.SortableIntField

My environment:
solr version 7.4.0
windows OS

Answer (score 0):

The SortableIntField [was removed in Solr 5](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/4_10_0/solr-core/org/apache/solr/schema/SortableIntField.html).

The haystack driver was updated in [PR#1148](https://github.com/django-haystack/django-haystack/pull/1148) to remove this dependency. Upgrade your version of haystack and regenerate the schema.